# Grid Background Image Opacity Animation

Tags: wpf, animation

Created a simple [jquery-nivo-like slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) using wpf and want to add an animation between slides that fades the background, changes the background image, and finally fades back in the new background image. I was trying to do the following....I get no errors, background changes, but there wasn't any animation either...what am I doing wrong?

```
public void SetSlider(MyItem item)
    {
        //Fade out
        DoubleAnimation fadeOutAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
        fadeOutAnimation.AutoReverse = false;
        grdContent.Background.BeginAnimation(Brush.OpacityProperty, fadeOutAnimation);

        //set background
        ImageBrush bgBrush = new ImageBrush();
        bgBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(item.ImageFile.SavedDirectoryAndFile, UriKind.Absolute));
        grdContent.Background = bgBrush;

        //Set title
        txtTitle.Text = item.Title;

        //set Summary
        txtSummary.Text = item.Summary;

        //Fade back in
        DoubleAnimation fadeInAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
        fadeInAnimation.AutoReverse = false;
        grdContent.Background.BeginAnimation(Brush.OpacityProperty, fadeInAnimation);        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out... I had to apply the animation to the brush that was set in the background property...not the background property itself and I had to make some timing changes. Here is my final solution:

```
public void SetSlider(MyItem item)
    {
        //Create the fade out animation. 
        DoubleAnimation fadeOutAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
        fadeOutAnimation.AutoReverse = false;

        //wait until the first animation is complete before changing the background, or else it will appear to just "fadeIn" with now fadeout.
        fadeOutAnimation.Completed += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //once the fadeout is complete set the new back ground and fade back in. 
            //Create a new background brush. 
            ImageBrush bgBrush = new ImageBrush();
            bgBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(item.ImageFile.SavedDirectoryAndFile, UriKind.Absolute));
            bgBrush.Opacity = 0;

            //Set the grid background to the new brush. 
            grdContent.Background = bgBrush; 

            //Set the brush...(not the background property) with the animation. 
            DoubleAnimation fadeInAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
            fadeInAnimation.AutoReverse = false;
            bgBrush.BeginAnimation(Brush.OpacityProperty, fadeInAnimation);
        };

        //Fade out..before changing the background. 
        var currentBackground = grdContent.Background;
        currentBackground.BeginAnimation(Brush.OpacityProperty, fadeOutAnimation);

        //Set title
        txtTitle.Text = item.Title;

        //set Summary
        txtSummary.Text = item.Summary;
    }
```

Comment: Best solution I've found soooooooooooo far, so thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach will be using [Transitional's](http://transitionals.codeplex.com) they have a sample project of image animation.

References:

```
xmlns:trans="clr-namespace:Transitionals;assembly=Transitionals"
xmlns:transc="clr-namespace:Transitionals.Controls;assembly=Transitionals"
xmlns:transt="clr-namespace:Transitionals.Transitions;assembly=Transitionals"
xmlns:refl="clr-namespace:System.Reflection;assembly=mscorlib"


 <transc:TransitionElement x:Name="TransitionBox" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding 
             CurrentImage}">
   <transc:TransitionElement.Transition>
      <transt:TranslateTransition StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="0,0"  
                Duration="0:0:0.6"/>
        </transc:TransitionElement.Transition>
    </transc:TransitionElement>
```

or use SlideShow Control it has if its an automatic Transition.

```
 <transc:Slideshow.TransitionSelector>
                <trans:RandomTransitionSelector>
                    <trans:RandomTransitionSelector.TransitionAssemblies>
                        <refl:AssemblyName Name="Transitionals" />
                    </trans:RandomTransitionSelector.TransitionAssemblies>
                </trans:RandomTransitionSelector>
 </transc:Slideshow.TransitionSelector>
```